# Start Day and End Day Of Current Month & Start Day & End Day of Current Year

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the current start date of the month and current end date of the month.

It needs to change for each month, so for example for this month I need:

```
$startMonth = 2014-02-01
$endMonth = 2014-02-28
```

I'm aware of the mktime PHP page but I can't get my head around it: https://www.php.net/mktime

I also need the start day and end day of the current year:

```
$startYear = 2014-01-01
$endYear = 2014-12-31
```

I need it in the above format, I can get the previous months using:

```
$previousmonthStart = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), 0, date("Y")));
$previousmonthEnd = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, 1, date("Y")));
```

Just need to know what changes what.

Comment: Not really, I would like to use the mktime function.

Comment: Why? There are better ways to do it then that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use `mktime()`...

I think the first day of the year and the last day of the current year are always (no `mktime()` needed):

```
date('Y') . '01-01'; 
date('Y') . '12-31';
```

For the first and last of the current month with `mktime()` try this:

```
$m = (integer) date('n');
$start = date('Y-m-d',mktime(1,1,1,$m,1,date('Y')));
$end   = date('Y-m-d',mktime(1,1,1,++$m,0,date('Y')));

//Considering today is 2014-02-05
echo $start; //2014-02-01
echo $end;   //2014-02-28
```

`mktime` wants hour, min, sec, month, day ,year

`$m` tells mktime to use the current month for the month value and the next `1` tells it to use the first day of that month.

`++$m` tells it to use the next month and the `0` gets you the day before the first day of the next month which is the last day of the current month.

Example: http://codepad.org/1G7UJNni